# Do increase Grenade damage on gear work with Strafe Demolition

Tags: diablo-iii-demon-hunter

If I enchant these pants for +Grenade damage, then would the grenades from Strafe Demolition increase in damage?
The Hellcat Waistguard makes the grenades from Strafe Demolition bounce so I am unsure about the +damage part.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately not, because the effect you are rolling in that screenshot is showing you available primary skills as replacements, and [Grenade](https://us.battle.net/d3/en/class/demon-hunter/active/grenade) (capital G) is a primary skill for the demon hunter.

The description for [Strafe's](https://us.battle.net/d3/en/class/demon-hunter/active/strafe) Demolition rune uses a lowercase G for "grenade", probably just to describe the visual effect of the rune, but does not in fact fire off an instance of the primary skill "Grenade".